# Overly large syntax highlighting function

Tags: parsing, rust, grammar

I've written [a text editor in Rust](https://github.com/isaacg1/text).

`make_highlights` is responsible for syntax highlighting. It takes a `Row`, which is just a wrapper around a `String`, and determines the appropriate syntax highlighting for each character. Currently, the function is very long - 84 lines - and thus hard to understand all at once. I'd like to break it up and make it more understandable.

```
impl Row {
    fn make_highlights(
        &self,
        syntax: &Option<EditorSyntax>,
        prev_open_quote: Option<char>,
    ) -> (Vec<EditorHighlight>, Option<char>) {
        if let Some(syntax) = syntax.as_ref() {
            let text: Vec<char> = self.text.chars().collect();
            let mut new_hls = vec![];
            let mut open_quote = if text.is_empty() {
                prev_open_quote
            } else {
                None
            };
            while new_hls.len() < text.len() {
                let prev_is_sep = new_hls.is_empty() || is_separator(text[new_hls.len() - 1]);
                if new_hls.is_empty() && prev_open_quote.is_some() ||
                    syntax.quotes.contains(text[new_hls.len()])
                {
                    let active_quote = if new_hls.is_empty() && prev_open_quote.is_some() {
                        prev_open_quote.expect("Just checked_it")
                    } else {
                        let start_quote = text[new_hls.len()];
                        new_hls.push(EditorHighlight::String);
                        start_quote
                    };
                    open_quote = Some(active_quote);
                    while new_hls.len() < text.len() {
                        if text[new_hls.len()] == active_quote {
                            new_hls.push(EditorHighlight::String);
                            open_quote = None;
                            break;
                        }
                        if text[new_hls.len()] == '\\' && new_hls.len() + 1 < text.len() {
                            new_hls.push(EditorHighlight::String);
                        }
                        new_hls.push(EditorHighlight::String);
                    }
                } else if syntax.has_digits && text[new_hls.len()].is_digit(10) && prev_is_sep {
                    while new_hls.len() < text.len() && text[new_hls.len()].is_digit(10) {
                        new_hls.push(EditorHighlight::Number);
                    }
                } else if self.text[new_hls.len()..].starts_with(syntax.singleline_comment) {
                    let chars_remaining = text.len() - new_hls.len();
                    new_hls.extend(repeat(EditorHighlight::Comment).take(chars_remaining));
                } else if prev_is_sep {
                    let following_string: String = self.text[new_hls.len()..].to_string();
                    let key_and_highlight: Vec<(usize, EditorHighlight)> = syntax
                        .keywords
                        .iter()
                        .enumerate()
                        .flat_map(|(highlight_index, keywords)| {
                            keywords
                                .iter()
                                .filter(|&keyword| {
                                    following_string.starts_with(keyword) &&
                                        (keyword.len() + new_hls.len() == text.len() ||
                                             is_separator(text[keyword.len() + new_hls.len()]))
                                })
                                .map(move |keyword| {
                                    (keyword.len(), EditorHighlight::KEYWORDS[highlight_index])
                                })
                        })
                        .collect();
                    assert!(key_and_highlight.len() <= 1);
                    if let Some(&(keyword_len, highlight)) = key_and_highlight.first() {
                        new_hls.extend(repeat(highlight).take(keyword_len));
                    } else {
                        new_hls.push(EditorHighlight::Normal);
                    }
                } else {
                    new_hls.push(EditorHighlight::Normal);
                }
            }
            (new_hls, open_quote)
        } else {
            (
                repeat(EditorHighlight::Normal)
                    .take(self.text.len())
                    .collect(),
                None,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant struct definitions and uses are:

```
use std::iter::repeat;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
enum EditorHighlight {
    Normal,
    Number,
    Match,
    String,
    Comment,
    Keyword1,
    Keyword2,
    Keyword3,
    Keyword4,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Row {
    text: String,
}

struct EditorSyntax<'a> {
    filetype: &'a str,
    extensions: Vec<&'a str>,
    has_digits: bool,
    quotes: &'a str,
    singleline_comment: &'a str,
    keywords: [Vec<&'a str>; 4],
}
```

The code also requires a nightly feature:

```
#![feature(associated_consts)]

impl EditorHighlight {
    const KEYWORDS: [Self; 4] = [
        EditorHighlight::Keyword1,
        EditorHighlight::Keyword2,
        EditorHighlight::Keyword3,
        EditorHighlight::Keyword4,
    ];
}
```

Other code:

```
fn is_separator(c: char) -> bool {
    c.is_whitespace() || "&{}'\",.()+-/*=~%<>[];:!".contains(c)
}
```

I am aware that this code is not UTF-8 compatible, that's on my to-do list to fix. I'd like advice on how to split it up, as well as how to generally improve it.

Comment: ``error[E0425]: cannot find function `is_separator` in this scope``: could you provide `is_separator` (or at the very least its contract)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`associated_consts` is stable since 1.20 (currently in beta). You don't need the attribute anymore. Other than that, you pass Clippy with no warnings.

You should almost certainly `#[derive(Debug)]` on `Row`, and depending on usage, it may also make sense to also derive the other derivable traits that `String` impls.

The biggest thing here is rightward drift.

The first thing to notice is that you've practically wrapped the entire method in an `if let` block. I'd extract the part that uses the `EditorSyntax` into its own fn.

```
fn make_highlights(
    &self,
    syntax: &Option<EditorSyntax>,
    prev_open_quote: Option<char>,
) -> (Vec<EditorHighlight>, Option<char>) {
    if let Some(syntax) = syntax.as_ref() {
        self.make_syntax_highlights(syntax, prev_open_quote);
    } else {
        (
            repeat(EditorHighlight::Normal)
                .take(self.text.chars().count())
                .collect(),
            None,
        )
    }
}
```

It might also make sense to just drop the form that doesn't take a `EditorSyntax` reference and just make a `EditorSyntax` that represents plain text.

```
const EMPTY_SYNTAX: EditorSyntax<'static> {
    filetype: "text",
    extensions: vec!["txt"],
    has_digits: false,
    quotes: "",
    // for lack of a better choice
    // what do languages without this kind of comment do?
    singleline_comment: "",
    keywords: [vec![],vec![],vec![],vec![]],
}
```

I would rename `new_hls` to something more obviously meaningful like `highlights`. You can also initialize it by using [`Vec::with_capacity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity) to set the required capacity and avoid having to reallocate the backing array.

```
fn make_syntax_highlights(
    &self,
    syntax: &EditorSyntax,
    prev_open_quote: Option<char>,
) -> (Vec<EditorHighlight>, Option<char>) {
    let text: Vec<char> = self.text.chars().collect();
    let mut highlights = Vec::with_capacity(text.len());
```

You can just initialize `open_quote` to `prev_open_quote` because you set it in your loop before using it.

```
    let mut open_quote = prev_open_quote;
```

dnt_abbr_ndlsly (don't abbreviate needlessly). `prev_is_sep` could be more clearly expressed as `starts_on_word_boundary`.

```
    while highlights.len() < text.len() {
        let starts_on_word_boundary = highlights.is_empty() ||
            is_separator(text[highlights.len() - 1]);
```

There is no reason to assign `active_quote`. Just assign into `open_quote` directly; this will also remove the need to unwrap `prev_open_quote`.

```
        if highlights.is_empty() && prev_open_quote.is_some() ||
            syntax.quotes.contains(text[highlights.len()])
        {
            open_quote = if highlights.is_empty() {
                prev_open_quote
            } else {
                highlights.push(EditorHighlight::String);
                Some(text[highlights.len()])
            };
```

I would check `open_quote.is_some()` in the loop condition here, allowing you to drop the `break`, and be 100% sure that you still have an open quote. I'd also move the unconditional push to the front of the loop.

```
            while open_quote.is_some() && highlights.len() < text.len() {
                highlights.push(EditorHighlight::String);
                if Some(text[highlights.len()]) == open_quote {
                    open_quote = None;
                } else if text[highlights.len()] == '\\' && highlights.len() < text.len() {
                    highlights.push(EditorHighlight::String);
                }
            }
```

Everything through the `starts_on_word_boundary` looks fine.

```
        } else if syntax.has_digits && text[highlights.len()].is_digit(10) &&
                   starts_on_word_boundary
        {
            while highlights.len() < text.len() && text[highlights.len()].is_digit(10) {
                highlights.push(EditorHighlight::Number);
            }
        } else if self.text[highlights.len()..].starts_with(syntax.singleline_comment) {
            let chars_remaining = text.len() - highlights.len();
            highlights.extend(repeat(EditorHighlight::Comment).take(chars_remaining));
        } else if starts_on_word_boundary {
            let following_string: String = self.text[highlights.len()..].to_string();
```

`key_and_highlight` looks fine, though a perfect target for an extract method refactoring. If I may self-advertise a little here, I would use the [Single](https://docs.rs/crate/single/0.2.1) crate here.

```
            let key_and_highlight: Vec<_> = syntax
                .keywords
                .iter()
                .enumerate()
                .flat_map(|(highlight_index, keywords)| {
                    keywords
                        .iter()
                        .filter(|&keyword| {
                            following_string.starts_with(keyword) &&
                                (keyword.len() + highlights.len() == text.len() ||
                                     is_separator(text[keyword.len() + highlights.len()]))
                        })
                        .map(move |keyword| {
                            (keyword.len(), EditorHighlight::KEYWORDS[highlight_index])
                        })
                })
                .single();
            let (keyword_len, highlight) =
                key_and_highlight.unwrap_or((1, EditorHighlight::Normal));
            highlights.extend(repeat(highlight).take(keyword_len));
        } else {
            highlights.push(EditorHighlight::Normal);
        }
    }
    (highlights, open_quote)
}
```

To avoid rightward draft, I'd extract any of the sections in the `if` chain that are more than two lines of code (excluding lines with just a `}`). Additionally consider extracting helper fn for the conditions long enough that rustfmt wraps them. And again, the `key_and_highlight` chain is a perfect target for adding as a helper fn on `EditorHighlight` or `Syntax`.

Also of note is that this syntax struct is very C-like language focused. If you try to add support for something like [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), I suspect you will need to expand your idea of what a syntax highlighter configuration needs to hold.

Comment: Thanks - this sort of thing is really helpful. I'll let you know if I have any questions as I go through things in detail.

Comment: Almost everything you said was correct and helpful. However, `open_quote = if highlights.is_empty() {` is an incorrect refactor - it should be `open_quote = if highlights.is_empty() && prev_open_quote.is_some() {`. Fortunately, my test cases caught it, so no harm done.

Comment: Also `Some(text[highlights.len()])` should be `Some(text[highlights.len() - 1])`, since it was moved past a push.